# Grabbing a service from anywhere in the app (Android)

Tags: android, service

I created a service that has to do a check repeatedly after a given amount of time, then it should communicate to my app the result of that check, no matter what the activity that app is in that precise time, it should respond to that message accordingly.

I got to the point where my service performs the check periodically, but I don't know how to grab this instance of the service from anywhere on my app, in order to get the results, stop the service when the app is in the background etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Spring Framework, you just can inject your service where you want it to be accessible in your program.

Otherwise you can work with the Singleton-Pattern. An example for the singleton pattern written in java can be found here: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html

Or just google "Singleton pattern example".
Hope that helps so far.

Comment: I think I might have misled you, I am developing for Android. What you understood for "service" is not exactly what I meant.